# Своя тема для shop script

Tags: веб-дизайн

Добрый день. Хочу сделать свою тему для shop script но документации, кроме как на официальном сайте не нашёл. Подскажите, если ли какой то ресурс, где этот процесс расписан детальнее, чем в офф. документации?